# Can't run Anaconda installer on Linux terminal

Tags: anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda from the website https://www.continuum.io/downloads and when I try to run the installer the running stops when I press "Enter" to accept the licence conditions. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work ?

Thanks 
Jamila

Comment: When I type "yes" it dosen't work either becsause I start having "y" within an infinite loop and I have to press ctrl+z to stop it

Comment: no, this is not my point. When you run the installer at some point it asks you to accept the license. You have to type yes there, just pressing enter will decline IIRC.

Comment: it asks me to print "enter" to continue the running if I agree with the licence, when I type "enter" it stops and when I type "yes" It goes into an infinite loop, so it doesn't work either ways.

Comment: Here it asks `Do you approve the license terms [yes|no]`. And you are supposed to write `yes`.

Comment: Actually I don't even get the chance to be asked to accept or not the licence, when I type "Enter" I have this message : "stopped  bash Anaconda2-2.4.0 -Linux-x86_64.sh"

Comment: But you do close the licence with `q` and not with `ctrl-c`?

Comment: The running stops by itself, I don't get any message about approving the licence